# How do I get the position of an element using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup

I have a fixed element in a HTML document and I need to get its position:

What is the approach for it?

I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = open("myFile.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup=markup.read(), features='html.parser')
markup.close()

spans = soup.find_all('span')
for sp in spans:
    print(sp.get('style'))
```

And it returned `None`

The element:

```
<span class="ocrx_word" id="word_1_304" title="bbox 1459 1183 1505 1205; x_wconf 77" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: sans-serif; position: fixed; left: 1459px; top: 1183px; width: 46px; height: 22px;">DC</span>
```

Here the position:

```
element.style {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: fixed;
 left: 1459px;
 top: 1183px;
 width: 46px;
 height: 22px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `markup` as a keyword arg?

Comment: You can use something like `sp["style"]`. That should work.

Comment: @ArmedinKuka I got error `KeyError: 'style'`

Comment: @JohnGordon does it change something?

Comment: Since it happens to be in the same position, I don't think it does.  I'm just curious why you're doing it that way.

Comment: In the loop, try printing `sp.attrs`.

Comment: Well, I got what I need using `sp.get('title').split()[3]`. I need the top position and it is on the title. But now I am curious how to get the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use `css selector` and search `span tag with style` attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<span class="ocrx_word" id="word_1_304" title="bbox 1459 1183 1505 1205; x_wconf 77" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: sans-serif; position: fixed; left: 1459px; top: 1183px; width: 46px; height: 22px;">DC</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

for item in soup.select("span[style]"):
    print(item['style'])
```